# angularjs ng-change in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

I want to cancel out the response in the answer field with an `ng-change` event on the drop down box. Need a way to dynamically access the answer field. The code is embedded in `ng-repeat` tags. Please refer [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0K4t8cx4rXsdH5fGrIp5?p=preview) for details.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I want to add a functionality for the following scenario. The user selects a question from the dropdown box, keys in the corresponding answer in the textbox below. Now he decides to change the question. On changing the question, I want to erase (blank out) whatever he had keyed in the answer box.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple things...

First you need to get rid of that second ng-repeat you have in there, it is completely unnecessary and messes up your $index which is required for the next step.

Remove

```
ng-repeat="(key, pair) in variable"
```

Then change your ng-options of your select to...

```
ng-options="var.questionDes for var in variable.questionList"
```

That extra ng-repeat was just a waste of space.

From there it's simple, all you need to do is add an ng-change to your select that will make the ng-model attached to the input an empty string, like so...

```
ng-change='answers[$index] = ""
```

Here is a working plunker for you http://plnkr.co/edit/5OgYSVhfNs5j7QCjF6vU?p=preview